# How can I solve this arithmetic puzzle? My solution is too slow after n = 14

Tags: python, math

Given numbers 1 to 3n, construct n equations of the form `a + b = c` or `a x b = c` such that each number is used exactly once. For example:

```
n=1 => 1+2=3
n=2 => 1+4=5, 2x3=6
n=3 => 4+5=9, 1+7=8, 2x3=6
```

The question is, does a solution exist for every n?

I tried writing a basic program and it becomes too slow after n = 14. Here are the solutions I have so far:

```
1 ['1+2=3']
2 ['2*3=6', '1+4=5']
3 ['4+5=9', '1+7=8', '2*3=6']
4 ['3+6=9', '1+10=11', '4+8=12', '2+5=7']
5 ['2+8=10', '3+6=9', '1+13=14', '5+7=12', '11+4=15']
6 ['3*5=15', '2+8=10', '4+14=18', '6+11=17', '7+9=16', '1+12=13']
7 ['6+12=18', '3*5=15', '7+10=17', '1+20=21', '4+9=13', '2+14=16', '8+11=19']
8 ['8+14=22', '6+12=18', '7+10=17', '2+19=21', '1+15=16', '11+13=24', '4+5=9', '3+20=23']
9 ['6+19=25', '8+14=22', '4+13=17', '2+18=20', '1+26=27', '3+7=10', '9+15=24', '5+16=21', '11+12=23']
10 ['6+19=25', '14+15=29', '11+17=28', '4+26=30', '2+18=20', '1+21=22', '3*9=27', '8+16=24', '5+7=12', '10+13=23']
11 ['10+23=33', '6+19=25', '14+15=29', '11+17=28', '4+26=30', '2+18=20', '5+27=32', '1+12=13', '9+22=31', '3*7=21', '16+8=24']
12 ['10+23=33', '3+29=32', '6+19=25', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '8+14=22', '4+16=20', '7+27=34', '2*12=24', '1+30=31', '5+13=18', '9+26=35']
13 ['10+23=33', '3+29=32', '7+30=37', '6+19=25', '5+34=39', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '18+20=38', '4+31=35', '1+26=27', '9+13=22', '8+16=24', '2+12=14']
14 ['10+23=33', '4+37=41', '3+29=32', '9+25=34', '15+21=36', '11+17=28', '8+14=22', '6+24=30', '13+27=40', '5*7=35', '2+18=20', '1+38=39', '12+19=31', '16+26=42']
```

Here's the code for the program:

```
import sys
from itertools import combinations

def main(n):
    r = set(range(1, n*3+1))
    print(n, solve(n, r, []))

def solve(n, lst, solution):
    if not lst:
        if len(solution) != n:
            return False
        return solution
    for c in combinations(lst, 3):
        valid_solution = valid(c)
        if valid_solution:
            new_solution = solution + [valid_solution]
            result = solve(n, set(lst) - set(c), new_solution)
            if result:
                return result
    return False

def valid(lst):
    a = lst[0]
    b = lst[1]
    c = lst[2]
    if a + b == c:
        return "%s+%s=%s" % (a, b, c)
    if a * b == c:
        return "%s*%s=%s" % (a, b, c)
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
   n = int(sys.argv[1])
   main(n)
```

Comment: This is a really interesting question! However if you find answers here lacking https://math.stackexchange.com/ may be more helpful for this particular problem.

Comment: Interesting problem. Since the question needs to be answered for every n, I'm not sure a numerical approach is best. If the answer is 'yes' then whatever algorithm you conceive of would have to run to infinity to prove it. Maybe try an analytical approach? E.g. prove that if a solution exists for n=i, then one must also exist for n=i+1. (just an idea, I don't really know the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I posted it on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271672/how-can-i-solve-this-arithmetic-puzzle. The algorithm approach doesn't help prove a solution exists for every n, but we might be able to use it to find a value of n for which there is no solution

Comment: i assume there is a missing `from itertools import combinations` in your code snippet?

Comment: Since you only iterate on `cs` once, there is no need to convert `combinations(lst, 3)` to a set. You can gain a bit of memory and speed by writing directly `for c in combinations(lst, 3):`

Comment: @Stef ya it's missing the import. I updated the code snippet with your suggestions but it's still too slow for n=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a combinatorial problem where its "messiness" suggests no mathematical answer can be formulated.  The cheer number of allowed combinations makes it ever more likely that each `n` has a valid solution, especially given that for small `n` you already found solutions.

Finding solutions for larger `n` can be tricky. One approach is called ["simulated annealing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), where you would take a random set of equations, I try to improve it step by step. "Bad equations" (i.e. equations that have numbers overlapping with others in the set) get removed, and new equations are tried.

Whatever approach is used, it probably can be speed up with heuristics. Such as start creating equations for numbers that show up in the least number of possible equations.

A somewhat related problem is called ["graceful labeling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling), which has no definite answer and for which similar algorithms are appropriate.

Here is an approach using [z3py](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm), a library which implements a [sat/smt solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories).

First, for each number, a list of possible expressions is made.  For each possible expression, a symbolic boolean indicates whether the expression will be used in the solution. To have a valid solution, for each number, exactly one of its possible expressions should be True.

```py
from z3 import Int, And, Or, Not, Bool, Sum, Solver, sat

def exactly_one(expr):
    return Or([And([(expr[j] == (i == j))
                    for j in range(len(expr))])
               for i in range(len(expr))])

for N in range(1, 43):
    exp_for_i = [[] for i in range(3 * N + 1)]
    expressions = []
    for i in range(1, 3 * N - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, 3 * N + 1):
            if i + j <= 3 * N:
                expr = Bool(f'{i}+{j}={i + j}')
                expressions.append(expr)
                exp_for_i[i].append(expr)
                exp_for_i[j].append(expr)
                exp_for_i[i + j].append(expr)
            if i > 1 and i * j <= 3 * N:
                expr = Int(f'{i}*{j}={i * j}')
                expressions.append(expr)
                exp_for_i[i].append(expr)
                exp_for_i[j].append(expr)
                exp_for_i[i * j].append(expr)

    s = Solver()
    s.add([exactly_one(expr) for expr in exp_for_i[1:]])
    if s.check() != sat:
        print(f'No solution for N={N}')
    else:
        m = s.model()
        print(f'N={N}:', [expr for expr in expressions if m.eval(expr) == True])
    s.reset()
```

```
N=1: [1+2=3]
N=2: [1+4=5, 2*3=6]
N=3: [1+7=8, 2*3=6, 4+5=9]
N=4: [1+10=11, 2*4=8, 3+6=9, 5+7=12]
N=5: [1+10=11, 2*7=14, 3*4=12, 5+8=13, 6+9=15]
N=6: [1+13=14, 2+7=9, 3*5=15, 4+12=16, 6+11=17, 8+10=18]
N=7: [1+17=18, 2+14=16, 3*5=15, 4+6=10, 7+13=20, 8+11=19, 9+12=21]
N=8: [1+18=19, 2+3=5, 4+17=21, 6+14=20, 7+9=16, 8+15=23, 10+12=22, 11+13=24]
N=9: [1+22=23, 2+19=21, 3+17=20, 4*6=24, 5+7=12, 8+10=18, 9+16=25, 11+15=26, 13+14=27]
N=10: [1+13=14, 2+23=25, 3*8=24, 4+22=26, 5+16=21, 6+9=15, 7+20=27, 10+19=29, 11+17=28, 12+18=30]
N=11: [1+23=24, 2*13=26, 3+25=28, 4+7=11, 5+22=27, 6+9=15, 8+21=29, 10+20=30, 12+19=31, 14+18=32, 16+17=33]
N=12: [1+6=7, 2+9=11, 3+26=29, 4+24=28, 5+25=30, 8+23=31, 10+22=32, 12+21=33, 13+14=27, 15+20=35, 16+18=34, 17+19=36]
N=13: [1+13=14, 2+8=10, 3+26=29, 4+28=32, 5+17=22, 6+25=31, 7+30=37, 9+24=33, 11+27=38, 12+23=35, 15+19=34, 16+20=36, 18+21=39]
N=14: [1+31=32, 2+12=14, 3*9=27, 4+30=34, 5+6=11, 7+28=35, 8+29=37, 10+26=36, 13+25=38, 15+24=39, 16+17=33, 18+23=41, 19+21=40, 20+22=42]
N=15: [1+5=6, 2+12=14, 3*11=33, 4+32=36, 7+31=38, 8+29=37, 9+30=39, 10+25=35, 13+28=41, 15+27=42, 16+18=34, 17+26=43, 19+21=40, 20+24=44, 22+23=45]
N=16: [1+25=26, 2+34=36, 3+11=14, 4+35=39, 5+37=42, 6+32=38, 7+13=20, 8+33=41, 9+10=19, 12+31=43, 15+29=44, 16+24=40, 17+30=47, 18+28=46, 21+27=48, 22+23=45]
N=17: [1+38=39, 2+25=27, 3+37=40, 4+13=17, 5+36=41, 6+9=15, 7+35=42, 8+11=19, 10+34=44, 12+33=45, 14+32=46, 16+31=47, 18+30=48, 20+29=49, 21+22=43, 23+28=51, 24+26=50]
N=18: [1+44=45, 2*25=50, 3+51=54, 4+42=46, 5+14=19, 6+22=28, 7+24=31, 8+33=41, 9+39=48, 10+30=40, 11+27=38, 12+35=47, 13+23=36, 15+37=52, 16+18=34, 17+26=43, 20+29=49, 21+32=53]
N=19: [1+18=19, 2+41=43, 3*14=42, 4+8=12, 5+40=45, 6+10=16, 7+39=46, 9+38=47, 11+37=48, 13+36=49, 15+35=50, 17+34=51, 20+33=53, 21+23=44, 22+32=54, 24+31=55, 25+27=52, 26+30=56, 28+29=57]
N=20: [1+44=45, 2+15=17, 3+43=46, 4+10=14, 5+42=47, 6+18=24, 7+41=48, 8+12=20, 9+40=49, 11+39=50, 13+38=51, 16+37=53, 19+36=55, 21+35=56, 22+30=52, 23+34=57, 25+33=58, 26+28=54, 27+32=59, 29+31=60]
N=21: [1+46=47, 2+17=19, 3+45=48, 4+7=11, 5+44=49, 6+15=21, 8+43=51, 9+13=22, 10+42=52, 12+41=53, 14+40=54, 16+39=55, 18+38=56, 20+37=57, 23+36=59, 24+26=50, 25+35=60, 27+34=61, 28+30=58, 29+33=62, 31+32=63]
N=22: [1+49=50, 2+21=23, 3*17=51, 4+15=19, 5+47=52, 6*8=48, 7+46=53, 9+45=54, 10+14=24, 11+44=55, 12+26=38, 13+43=56, 16+42=58, 18+41=59, 20+40=60, 22+39=61, 25+37=62, 27+36=63, 28+29=57, 30+35=65, 31+33=64, 32+34=66]
N=23: [1+40=41, 2*27=54, 3+13=16, 4+42=46, 5+62=67, 6+55=61, 7+45=52, 8+49=57, 9+59=68, 10+56=66, 11+14=25, 12+48=60, 15+29=44, 17+34=51, 18+35=53, 19+39=58, 20+30=50, 21+22=43, 23+24=47, 26+38=64, 28+37=65, 31+32=63, 33+36=69]
N=24: [1+18=19, 2+53=55, 3+51=54, 4*14=56, 5+52=57, 6+7=13, 8+21=29, 9+16=25, 10+49=59, 11+47=58, 12+48=60, 15+46=61, 17+45=62, 20+44=64, 22+43=65, 23+27=50, 24+42=66, 26+41=67, 28+40=68, 30+39=69, 31+32=63, 33+38=71, 34+36=70, 35+37=72]
N=25: [1+57=58, 2*32=64, 3+60=63, 4+41=45, 5+37=42, 6+69=75, 7+46=53, 8+62=70, 9+13=22, 10+49=59, 11+29=40, 12+61=73, 14+25=39, 15+35=50, 16+52=68, 17+55=72, 18+48=66, 19+24=43, 20+47=67, 21+30=51, 23+33=56, 26+28=54, 27+44=71, 31+34=65, 36+38=74]
N=26: [1+70=71, 2*17=34, 3+26=29, 4+44=48, 5+18=23, 6+57=63, 7+66=73, 8+37=45, 9+51=60, 10+68=78, 11+61=72, 12+52=64, 13+43=56, 14+40=54, 15+50=65, 16+33=49, 19+39=58, 20+55=75, 21+53=74, 22+25=47, 24+38=62, 27+42=69, 28+31=59, 30+46=76, 32+35=67, 36+41=77]
N=27: [1+15=16, 2*30=60, 3+58=61, 4+18=22, 5+57=62, 6+20=26, 7*9=63, 8+56=64, 10+55=65, 11+13=24, 12+54=66, 14+53=67, 17+52=69, 19+51=70, 21+50=71, 23+49=72, 25+48=73, 27+47=74, 28+31=59, 29+46=75, 32+45=77, 33+35=68, 34+44=78, 36+43=79, 37+39=76, 38+42=80, 40+41=81]
N=28: [1+61=62, 2+20=22, 3+68=71, 4+49=53, 5+51=56, 6+35=41, 7+70=77, 8+21=29, 9+57=66, 10+13=23, 11+54=65, 12+64=76, 14+67=81, 15+58=73, 16+34=50, 17+46=63, 18+24=42, 19+60=79, 25+55=80, 26+33=59, 27+48=75, 28+44=72, 30+52=82, 31+47=78, 32+37=69, 36+38=74, 39+45=84, 40+43=83]
N=29: [1+64=65, 2+61=63, 3+26=29, 4+27=31, 5+17=22, 6+74=80, 7+48=55, 8+62=70, 9+11=20, 10+43=53, 12+69=81, 13+54=67, 14+57=71, 15+21=36, 16+52=68, 18+60=78, 19+58=77, 23+56=79, 24+49=73, 25+59=84, 28+44=72, 30+45=75, 32+34=66, 33+50=83, 35+51=86, 37+39=76, 38+47=85, 40+42=82, 41+46=87]
N=30: [1+64=65, 2+28=30, 3*22=66, 4+63=67, 5+15=20, 6+26=32, 7+62=69, 8+9=17, 10+61=71, 11+13=24, 12+60=72, 14+59=73, 16+58=74, 18+70=88, 19+57=76, 21+56=77, 23+55=78, 25+54=79, 27+53=80, 29+52=81, 31+51=82, 33+35=68, 34+50=84, 36+49=85, 37+38=75, 39+48=87, 40+43=83, 41+45=86, 42+47=89, 44+46=90]
N=31: [1+69=70, 2+83=85, 3+20=23, 4+75=79, 5+68=73, 6*7=42, 8+82=90, 9+41=50, 10+43=53, 11+46=57, 12+51=63, 13+39=52, 14+66=80, 15+25=40, 16+76=92, 17+64=81, 18+56=74, 19+59=78, 21+37=58, 22+71=93, 24+48=72, 26+35=61, 27+62=89, 28+60=88, 29+36=65, 30+54=84, 31+55=86, 32+45=77, 33+34=67, 38+49=87, 44+47=91]
N=32: [1+75=76, 2*36=72, 3+74=77, 4+17=21, 5+24=29, 6+67=73, 7+19=26, 8+58=66, 9+53=62, 10+85=95, 11+60=71, 12+68=80, 13+20=33, 14+79=93, 15+39=54, 16+41=57, 18+65=83, 22+48=70, 23+61=84, 25+56=81, 27+63=90, 28+64=92, 30+59=89, 31+47=78, 32+55=87, 34+35=69, 37+49=86, 38+50=88, 40+42=82, 43+51=94, 44+52=96, 45+46=91]
N=33: [1+27=28, 2+73=75, 3+22=25, 4+72=76, 5+11=16, 6+71=77, 7+54=61, 8+70=78, 9+23=32, 10+69=79, 12+18=30, 13+68=81, 14+20=34, 15+67=82, 17+66=83, 19+65=84, 21+64=85, 24+63=87, 26+62=88, 29+60=89, 31+59=90, 33+58=91, 35+57=92, 36+38=74, 37+56=93, 39+41=80, 40+55=95, 42+44=86, 43+53=96, 45+52=97, 46+48=94, 47+51=98, 49+50=99]
N=34: [1+74=75, 2+19=21, 3+73=76, 4+28=32, 5+18=23, 6*13=78, 7+70=77, 8+71=79, 9+72=81, 10+24=34, 11+69=80, 12+26=38, 14+16=30, 15+68=83, 17+67=84, 20+66=86, 22+65=87, 25+64=89, 27+63=90, 29+62=91, 31+61=92, 33+60=93, 35+59=94, 36+49=85, 37+58=95, 39+57=96, 40+42=82, 41+56=97, 43+45=88, 44+55=99, 46+54=100, 47+51=98, 48+53=101, 50+52=102]
N=35: [1+62=63, 2+76=78, 3*25=75, 4*24=96, 5+94=99, 6+59=65, 7+74=81, 8+82=90, 9+38=47, 10+57=67, 11+73=84, 12+31=43, 13+21=34, 14+86=100, 15+49=64, 16+85=101, 17+60=77, 18+80=98, 19+23=42, 20+71=91, 22+50=72, 26+79=105, 27+61=88, 28+41=69, 29+68=97, 30+36=66, 32+55=87, 33+70=103, 35+58=93, 37+46=83, 39+56=95, 40+52=92, 44+45=89, 48+54=102, 51+53=104]
N=36: [1+81=82, 2+24=26, 3+76=79, 4+15=19, 5+78=83, 6+31=37, 7+77=84, 8+35=43, 9+21=30, 10+75=85, 11+17=28, 12+74=86, 13+23=36, 14+73=87, 16+72=88, 18+71=89, 20+70=90, 22+69=91, 25+68=93, 27+67=94, 29+66=95, 32+65=97, 33+63=96, 34+64=98, 38+62=100, 39+41=80, 40+61=101, 42+60=102, 44+59=103, 45+47=92, 46+58=104, 48+57=105, 49+50=99, 51+56=107, 52+54=106, 53+55=108]
N=37: [1+76=77, 2+65=67, 3+37=40, 4+23=27, 5+55=60, 6+103=109, 7+87=94, 8+80=88, 9+66=75, 10+31=41, 11+47=58, 12+84=96, 13+59=72, 14+91=105, 15+93=108, 16+79=95, 17+73=90, 18+30=48, 19+78=97, 20+62=82, 21+71=92, 22+89=111, 24+61=85, 25+39=64, 26+42=68, 28+35=63, 29+81=110, 32+74=106, 33+69=102, 34+70=104, 36+50=86, 38+45=83, 43+57=100, 44+54=98, 46+53=99, 49+52=101, 51+56=107]
N=38: [1+83=84, 2+32=34, 3*9=27, 4+82=86, 5+15=20, 6+81=87, 7+23=30, 8+80=88, 10+79=89, 11+25=36, 12+78=90, 13+16=29, 14+77=91, 17+76=93, 18+22=40, 19+75=94, 21+74=95, 24+73=97, 26+72=98, 28+71=99, 31+70=101, 33+69=102, 35+68=103, 37+67=104, 38+58=96, 39+66=105, 41+65=106, 42+43=85, 44+64=108, 45+47=92, 46+63=109, 48+62=110, 49+51=100, 50+61=111, 52+60=112, 53+54=107, 55+59=114, 56+57=113]
N=39: [1+86=87, 2*19=38, 3+85=88, 4*10=40, 5+84=89, 6+30=36, 7+83=90, 8+34=42, 9+82=91, 11+81=92, 12+14=26, 13+80=93, 15+17=32, 16+79=95, 18+78=96, 20+77=97, 21+23=44, 22+76=98, 24+75=99, 25+28=53, 27+74=101, 29+73=102, 31+72=103, 33+71=104, 35+70=105, 37+69=106, 39+68=107, 41+67=108, 43+66=109, 45+65=110, 46+48=94, 47+64=111, 49+51=100, 50+63=113, 52+62=114, 54+61=115, 55+57=112, 56+60=116, 58+59=117]
N=40: [1+96=97, 2+85=87, 3+60=63, 4+69=73, 5+104=109, 6+76=82, 7+71=78, 8+53=61, 9+58=67, 10+98=108, 11+106=117, 12+14=26, 13+28=41, 15+90=105, 16+86=102, 17+33=50, 18+81=99, 19+29=48, 20+42=62, 21+59=80, 22+91=113, 23+77=100, 24+94=118, 25+95=120, 27+74=101, 30+49=79, 31+83=114, 32+84=116, 34+54=88, 35+40=75, 36+56=92, 37+52=89, 38+65=103, 39+72=111, 43+64=107, 44+66=110, 45+70=115, 46+47=93, 51+68=119, 55+57=112]
N=41: [1+110=111, 2+13=15, 3+51=54, 4+77=81, 5+84=89, 6+97=103, 7+99=106, 8+85=93, 9+11=20, 10+34=44, 12+75=87, 14+43=57, 16+79=95, 17+88=105, 18+98=116, 19+90=109, 21+96=117, 22+64=86, 23+37=60, 24+70=94, 25+42=67, 26+39=65, 27+74=101, 28+55=83, 29+78=107, 30+92=122, 31+35=66, 32+59=91, 33+82=115, 36+72=108, 38+76=114, 40+80=120, 41+63=104, 45+68=113, 46+56=102, 47+53=100, 48+73=121, 49+69=118, 50+62=112, 52+71=123, 58+61=119]
N=42: [1+88=89, 2+94=96, 3*42=126, 4+47=51, 5+109=114, 6+69=75, 7+52=59, 8+33=41, 9+108=117, 10+60=70, 11+84=95, 12+111=123, 13+48=61, 14+85=99, 15+43=58, 16+81=97, 17+38=55, 18+80=98, 19+34=53, 20+105=125, 21+103=124, 22+68=90, 23+87=110, 24+83=107, 25+67=92, 26+56=82, 27+91=118, 28+78=106, 29+86=115, 30+71=101, 31+73=104, 32+40=72, 35+65=100, 36+66=102, 37+79=116, 39+54=93, 44+77=121, 45+74=119, 46+76=122, 49+64=113, 50+62=112, 57+63=120]
N=43: [1+79=80, 2+109=111, 3*14=42, 4+50=54, 5+112=117, 6+89=95, 7+90=97, 8+21=29, 9+74=83, 10+88=98, 11+32=43, 12+114=126, 13+110=123, 15+103=118, 16+68=84, 17+35=52, 18+59=77, 19+86=105, 20+82=102, 22+34=56, 23+58=81, 24+101=125, 25+60=85, 26+96=122, 27+100=127, 28+93=121, 30+61=91, 31+63=94, 33+66=99, 36+70=106, 37+76=113, 38+49=87, 39+65=104, 40+67=107, 41+78=119, 44+48=92, 45+71=116, 46+62=108, 47+73=120, 51+64=115, 53+75=128, 55+69=124, 57+72=129]
N=44: [1+28=29, 2+83=85, 3+86=89, 4+117=121, 5+96=101, 6+42=48, 7+70=77, 8+118=126, 9+30=39, 10+100=110, 11+120=131, 12+80=92, 13+82=95, 14+19=33, 15+51=66, 16+90=106, 17+99=116, 18+53=71, 20+107=127, 21+36=57, 22+81=103, 23+109=132, 24+91=115, 25+54=79, 26+97=123, 27+67=94, 31+88=119, 32+72=104, 34+78=112, 35+63=98, 37+74=111, 38+84=122, 40+47=87, 41+73=114, 43+50=93, 44+58=102, 45+60=105, 46+62=108, 49+76=125, 52+61=113, 55+75=130, 56+68=124, 59+69=128, 64+65=129]
N=45: [1+41=42, 2+98=100, 3+92=95, 4+97=101, 5+48=53, 6+122=128, 7+107=114, 8+62=70, 9+102=111, 10+108=118, 11+73=84, 12+21=33, 13+78=91, 14+112=126, 15+65=80, 16+45=61, 17+49=66, 18+29=47, 19+74=93, 20+55=75, 22+68=90, 23+56=79, 24+105=129, 25+110=135, 26+99=125, 27+86=113, 28+39=67, 30+85=115, 31+96=127, 32+89=121, 34+72=106, 35+88=123, 36+94=130, 37+87=124, 38+82=120, 40+69=109, 43+76=119, 44+59=103, 46+58=104, 50+83=133, 51+81=132, 52+64=116, 54+77=131, 57+60=117, 63+71=134]
N=46: [1+100=101, 2+128=130, 3*34=102, 4+121=125, 5+24=29, 6+30=36, 7+40=47, 8+58=66, 9+32=41, 10+124=134, 11+67=78, 12+115=127, 13+83=96, 14+91=105, 15+57=72, 16+73=89, 17+87=104, 18+81=99, 19+60=79, 20+97=117, 21+95=116, 22+62=84, 23+53=76, 25+93=118, 26+103=129, 27+108=135, 28+85=113, 31+88=119, 33+90=123, 35+71=106, 37+74=111, 38+69=107, 39+98=137, 42+80=122, 43+51=94, 44+92=136, 45+75=120, 46+68=114, 48+64=112, 49+82=131, 50+59=109, 52+86=138, 54+56=110, 55+77=132, 61+65=126, 63+70=133]
N=47: [1+102=103, 2+41=43, 3+45=48, 4*26=104, 5+32=37, 6+101=107, 7*15=105, 8+100=108, 9+24=33, 10+99=109, 11+35=46, 12+98=110, 13+17=30, 14+97=111, 16+96=112, 18+95=113, 19+20=39, 21+94=115, 22+28=50, 23+93=116, 25+92=117, 27+91=118, 29+90=119, 31+89=120, 34+88=122, 36+87=123, 38+86=124, 40+85=125, 42+84=126, 44+83=127, 47+82=129, 49+81=130, 51+80=131, 52+54=106, 53+79=132, 55+78=133, 56+58=114, 57+77=134, 59+76=135, 60+61=121, 62+75=137, 63+65=128, 64+74=138, 66+73=139, 67+69=136, 68+72=140, 70+71=141]
N=48: [1+126=127, 2*26=52, 3+105=108, 4+103=107, 5+101=106, 6+31=37, 7+102=109, 8+33=41, 9+39=48, 10+100=110, 11+35=46, 12+99=111, 13+16=29, 14+28=42, 15+98=113, 17+97=114, 18+22=40, 19+96=115, 20+24=44, 21+95=116, 23+94=117, 25+93=118, 27+92=119, 30+91=121, 32+90=122, 34+89=123, 36+88=124, 38+87=125, 43+86=129, 45+85=130, 47+84=131, 49+83=132, 50+54=104, 51+82=133, 53+81=134, 55+57=112, 56+80=136, 58+79=137, 59+61=120, 60+78=138, 62+77=139, 63+65=128, 64+76=140, 66+75=141, 67+68=135, 69+74=143, 70+72=142, 71+73=144]
N=49: [1+136=137, 2+34=36, 3+135=138, 4+126=130, 5+61=66, 6+32=38, 7+81=88, 8+109=117, 9+105=114, 10+58=68, 11+120=131, 12+80=92, 13+42=55, 14+97=111, 15+71=86, 16+102=118, 17+46=63, 18+101=119, 19+122=141, 20+112=132, 21+48=69, 22+94=116, 23+29=52, 24+91=115, 25+75=100, 26+98=124, 27+106=133, 28+79=107, 30+99=129, 31+96=127, 33+70=103, 35+37=72, 39+89=128, 40+73=113, 41+82=123, 43+65=108, 44+60=104, 45+95=140, 47+74=121, 49+76=125, 50+84=134, 51+59=110, 53+93=146, 54+90=144, 56+87=143, 57+85=142, 62+77=139, 64+83=147, 67+78=145]
N=50: [1+7=8, 2+40=42, 3*37=111, 4+109=113, 5+39=44, 6+108=114, 9+106=115, 10+35=45, 11+105=116, 12+15=27, 13+104=117, 14+33=47, 16+103=119, 17+95=112, 18+102=120, 19+32=51, 20+29=49, 21+101=122, 22+99=121, 23+100=123, 24+107=131, 25+30=55, 26+98=124, 28+97=125, 31+96=127, 34+94=128, 36+93=129, 38+92=130, 41+91=132, 43+90=133, 46+89=135, 48+88=136, 50+87=137, 52+86=138, 53+57=110, 54+85=139, 56+84=140, 58+60=118, 59+83=142, 61+82=143, 62+64=126, 63+81=144, 65+80=145, 66+68=134, 67+79=146, 69+78=147, 70+71=141, 72+77=149, 73+75=148, 74+76=150]
N=51: [1+51=52, 2+111=113, 3+38=41, 4+45=49, 5+110=115, 6*19=114, 7+109=116, 8*14=112, 9+108=117, 10+24=34, 11+32=43, 12+107=119, 13+26=39, 15+105=120, 16+31=47, 17+104=121, 18+36=54, 20+103=123, 21+101=122, 22+102=124, 23+106=129, 25+100=125, 27+29=56, 28+99=127, 30+98=128, 33+97=130, 35+96=131, 37+95=132, 40+94=134, 42+93=135, 44+92=136, 46+91=137, 48+90=138, 50+89=139, 53+88=141, 55+87=142, 57+86=143, 58+60=118, 59+85=144, 61+84=145, 62+64=126, 63+83=146, 65+82=147, 66+67=133, 68+81=149, 69+71=140, 70+80=150, 72+79=151, 73+75=148, 74+78=152, 76+77=153]
N=52: [1+115=116, 2+17=19, 3+114=117, 4+50=54, 5+113=118, 6+37=43, 7+38=45, 8+111=119, 9+112=121, 10+13=23, 11+109=120, 12+110=122, 14+33=47, 15+108=123, 16+32=48, 18+107=125, 20+106=126, 21+35=56, 22+105=127, 24+104=128, 25+27=52, 26+103=129, 28+102=130, 29+31=60, 30+101=131, 34+99=133, 36+98=134, 39+97=136, 40+95=135, 41+96=137, 42+58=100, 44+94=138, 46+93=139, 49+92=141, 51+91=142, 53+90=143, 55+89=144, 57+88=145, 59+87=146, 61+63=124, 62+86=148, 64+85=149, 65+67=132, 66+84=150, 68+83=151, 69+71=140, 70+82=152, 72+81=153, 73+74=147, 75+80=155, 76+78=154, 77+79=156]
N=53: [1+114=115, 2+30=32, 3+113=116, 4+38=42, 5+51=56, 6+43=49, 7*17=119, 8+112=120, 9*13=117, 10+111=121, 11+34=45, 12+110=122, 14+109=123, 15+25=40, 16+108=124, 18+107=125, 19+36=55, 20+27=47, 21+106=127, 22+129=151, 23+105=128, 24+29=53, 26+104=130, 28+103=131, 31+102=133, 33+101=134, 35+100=135, 37+99=136, 39+98=137, 41+97=138, 44+96=140, 46+95=141, 48+94=142, 50+93=143, 52+92=144, 54+91=145, 57+90=147, 58+60=118, 59+89=148, 61+88=149, 62+64=126, 63+87=150, 65+67=132, 66+86=152, 68+85=153, 69+70=139, 71+84=155, 72+74=146, 73+83=156, 75+82=157, 76+78=154, 77+81=158, 79+80=159]
N=54: [1+22=23, 2+57=59, 3*42=126, 4+91=95, 5+136=141, 6+52=58, 7+37=44, 8+104=112, 9+153=162, 10+46=56, 11+113=124, 12+115=127, 13+84=97, 14+118=132, 15+119=134, 16+133=149, 17+63=80, 18+96=114, 19+139=158, 20+31=51, 21+62=83, 24+74=98, 25+121=146, 26+116=142, 27+120=147, 28+81=109, 29+99=128, 30+105=135, 32+129=161, 33+107=140, 34+88=122, 35+108=143, 36+87=123, 38+100=138, 39+72=111, 40+53=93, 41+69=110, 43+102=145, 45+92=137, 47+70=117, 48+103=151, 49+101=150, 50+106=156, 54+90=144, 55+76=131, 60+65=125, 61+94=155, 64+66=130, 67+85=152, 68+89=157, 71+77=148, 73+86=159, 75+79=154, 78+82=160]
N=55: [1+31=32, 2*76=152, 3+138=141, 4+62=66, 5*21=105, 6+159=165, 7+58=65, 8+117=125, 9+144=153, 10+147=157, 11+73=84, 12+83=95, 13+118=131, 14+55=69, 15+124=139, 16+146=162, 17+61=78, 18+103=121, 19+70=89, 20+116=136, 22+107=129, 23+92=115, 24+110=134, 25+112=137, 26+94=120, 27+122=149, 28+130=158, 29+111=140, 30+96=126, 33+75=108, 34+127=161, 35+74=109, 36+114=150, 37+91=128, 38+41=79, 39+54=93, 40+102=142, 42+106=148, 43+80=123, 44+46=90, 45+88=133, 47+98=145, 48+49=97, 50+104=154, 51+100=151, 52+67=119, 53+60=113, 56+99=155, 57+86=143, 59+101=160, 63+72=135, 64+68=132, 71+85=156, 77+87=164, 81+82=163]
N=56: [1+53=54, 2+122=124, 3*41=123, 4+121=125, 5+51=56, 6*21=126, 7+120=127, 8+28=36, 9+119=128, 10+39=49, 11+118=129, 12+26=38, 13+45=58, 14+117=131, 15+19=34, 16+116=132, 17+43=60, 18+115=133, 20+114=134, 22+113=135, 23+24=47, 25+112=137, 27+111=138, 29+110=139, 30+32=62, 31+109=140, 33+108=141, 35+107=142, 37+106=143, 40+105=145, 42+104=146, 44+103=147, 46+102=148, 48+101=149, 50+100=150, 52+99=151, 55+98=153, 57+97=154, 59+96=155, 61+95=156, 63+94=157, 64+66=130, 65+93=158, 67+69=136, 68+92=160, 70+91=161, 71+73=144, 72+90=162, 74+89=163, 75+77=152, 76+88=164, 78+87=165, 79+80=159, 81+86=167, 82+84=166, 83+85=168]
N=57: [1+36=37, 2+149=151, 3+56=59, 4+166=170, 5+80=85, 6+135=141, 7+114=121, 8+90=98, 9+128=137, 10+113=123, 11+143=154, 12+148=160, 13+47=60, 14+52=66, 15+150=165, 16+100=116, 17+34=51, 18+146=164, 19+140=159, 20+53=73, 21+115=136, 22+110=132, 23+102=125, 24+88=112, 25+78=103, 26+79=105, 27+74=101, 28+134=162, 29+129=158, 30+89=119, 31+107=138, 32+139=171, 33+75=108, 35+109=144, 38+104=142, 39+57=96, 40+117=157, 41+106=147, 42+76=118, 43+87=130, 44+83=127, 45+124=169, 46+99=145, 48+63=111, 49+84=133, 50+70=120, 54+77=131, 55+67=122, 58+94=152, 61+65=126, 62+91=153, 64+92=156, 68+93=161, 69+86=155, 71+97=168, 72+95=167, 81+82=163]
N=58: [1+127=128, 2+16=18, 3+126=129, 4+50=54, 5*26=130, 6+125=131, 7+52=59, 8+124=132, 9+33=42, 10+123=133, 11+35=46, 12+122=134, 13+31=44, 14+121=135, 15+48=63, 17+120=137, 19+119=138, 20+37=57, 21+118=139, 22+39=61, 23+117=140, 24+41=65, 25+116=141, 27+29=56, 28+115=143, 30+114=144, 32+113=145, 34+112=146, 36+111=147, 38+110=148, 40+109=149, 43+108=151, 45+107=152, 47+106=153, 49+105=154, 51+104=155, 53+103=156, 55+102=157, 58+101=159, 60+100=160, 62+99=161, 64+98=162, 66+97=163, 67+69=136, 68+96=164, 70+72=142, 71+95=166, 73+94=167, 74+76=150, 75+93=168, 77+92=169, 78+80=158, 79+91=170, 81+90=171, 82+83=165, 84+89=173, 85+87=172, 86+88=174]
N=59: [1+129=130, 2+47=49, 3+128=131, 4+54=58, 5+40=45, 6*22=132, 7+127=134, 8+20=28, 9*15=135, 10+126=136, 11+41=52, 12+125=137, 13+38=51, 14+124=138, 16+123=139, 17+43=60, 18+122=140, 19+72=91, 21+121=142, 23+120=143, 24+32=56, 25+119=144, 26+36=62, 27+118=145, 29+117=146, 30+34=64, 31+116=147, 33+115=148, 35+114=149, 37+113=150, 39+112=151, 42+111=153, 44+110=154, 46+109=155, 48+108=156, 50+107=157, 53+106=159, 55+105=160, 57+104=161, 59+103=162, 61+102=163, 63+101=164, 65+100=165, 66+67=133, 68+73=141, 69+99=168, 70+97=167, 71+98=169, 74+96=170, 75+77=152, 76+95=171, 78+80=158, 79+94=173, 81+93=174, 82+84=166, 83+92=175, 85+87=172, 86+90=176, 88+89=177]
N=60: [1+125=126, 2*71=142, 3+148=151, 4+74=78, 5+168=173, 6+91=97, 7*20=140, 8+81=89, 9+158=167, 10+47=57, 11+128=139, 12+164=176, 13+124=137, 14+18=32, 15+75=90, 16+66=82, 17+45=62, 19+93=112, 21+38=59, 22+100=122, 23+130=153, 24+121=145, 25+102=127, 26+88=114, 27+143=170, 28+95=123, 29+109=138, 30+136=166, 31+70=101, 33+129=162, 34+118=152, 35+106=141, 36+98=134, 37+132=169, 39+41=80, 40+77=117, 42+104=146, 43+135=178, 44+133=177, 46+108=154, 48+113=161, 49+61=110, 50+99=149, 51+120=171, 52+79=131, 53+119=172, 54+111=165, 55+92=147, 56+103=159, 58+86=144, 60+115=175, 63+94=157, 64+116=180, 65+85=150, 67+96=163, 68+87=155, 69+105=174, 72+107=179, 73+83=156, 76+84=160]
```